# Change background image based on hour of day

Tags: javascript, css

i have a some code that should change the background based on the hour of day. This will be running all the time in my own home, so I need help getting it to work and to refresh every 5 minutes or so. How i think it should work is it'll take a look at what hour it is, follow some logic and then write out the next line as

Can you help me find out why it doesn't work and how to fix it? I'm new to coding, don't know a whole lot.

EDIT: I don't know what the error is, it just doesn't change the background, it stays white

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var now = new Date();
    var hours = now.getHours();

    //Place this script in your HTML heading section

    //1-2am
    if (hours >= 1 && hours < 3){
    document.write(<body background="11.png">);
    }
    //3-4am
    else if (hours >= 3 && hours < 5){
    document.write(<body background="12.png">);
    }
    //5-6am
    else if (hours >= 5 && hours < 7){
    document.write(<body background="1.png">);
    }
    //7-8am
    else if (hours >= 7 && hours < 9){
    document.write(<body background="2.png">);
    }
    //9-10am
    else if (hours >= 9 && hours < 11){
    document.write(<body background="3.png">);
    }
    //11-12pm
    else if (hours >= 11 && hours < 13){
    document.write(<body background="4.png">);
    }
    //1-2Pm
    else if (hours >= 13 || hours < 15){
    document.write(<body background="5.png">);
    }
    //3-4pm
    else if (hours >= 15 && hours < 17){
    document.write(<body background="6.png">);
    }
    //5-6pm
    else if (hours >= 17 && hours < 19){
    document.write(<body background="7.png">);
    }   
    //7-8 pm
    else if (hours >= 19 && hours < 21){
    document.write(<body background="9.png">);
    }       
    //10-12am
    else {
    document.write(<body background="10.png">);
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: `Can you help me find the error and how to fix it?` Which error? You haven't said what the question is??

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what the error is, it just won't update the wallpaper, it's always white

Comment: OK- google `css background image` for a start - `body background="11.png"` will do nothing

Comment: Press F12 to open your browser's developer tools and look at the console tab

Comment: If i write the next line of the code as <body background="11,png"> it will make the background that image, so i tried to make the code do the same thing. This is in HTML by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeBg() {
    var now = new Date();
    var hours = now.getHours();

    //based on hours it will dynamically change the image
        //1.png, 2.png, ..., 23.png
        document.body.style.backgroundImage ="url('" + hours + ".png')"

 }
changeBg();
 setInterval(function(){ changeBg(); }, 300000); //300000 means 5 min
</script>
```

Comment: This worked, but it won't update on launch, only after some time, (probably 5 minutes). How can I get it to update when i load the page

Comment: Kindly call the function ChangeBg() after or before   setInterval(function(){ changeBg(""); }, 300000);

Comment: what is you current hours and did you have the respective png file eg: 4.png

Comment: It's 4pm + 12 = 16 and yes

Comment: FYI you don't need `type="text/javascript"` and you can shorten it to `setInterval(changeBg, 300000)`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background dynamically.  Notice the pattern with the times and corresponding image names.  You can map one to the other to shorten your code by quite a large amount.  Also, I would recommend not writing the body tag over and over again, rather change the body tag's CSS background.

Of course, this code would only execute once, so you need to call it at some fixed interval so that it will update on time.  You can use `setInterval` for that.  This function takes a callback function as the first argument and a time in milliseconds of how long you want the interval to be.  Since the background only changes once every two hours, you can just execute the function maybe once a minute.  One minute in milliseconds is `1 * 60 * 1000`;

```
setInterval(function() {
    var now = new Date();
    var hours = now.getHours();
    var imgName = (Math.floor((hours + 23) / 2) + 10) % 12 + 1;

    //Place this script in your HTML heading section
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = imgName + ".png";
}, 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: [10) % 12] mathematically speaking, what does that percent sign mean

Comment: That would be the remainder operator.  You can read about it at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()